# How to use the `match` keyword to match a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, python-3.10

Is it possible to use the new `match` keyword to match a range of characters?

Basically to do something like this?

```py
match "b":
    case "a":
        print("a")
    case range("a", "z"):
        print("alphabet")
```

If not, what are the *cheap in characters* alternatives ?

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs.

Comment: You can use an or-pattern to list each possibility explicitly: `case "a"|"b"|"c":`; but that's probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: Class patterns (which is what your example resembles) are meant to mimic the constructor for the value being matched, not as a way to represent multiple possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define a class which has an instance that can compare equal to `"b"`, then find a way to refer to such an object using a dotted name. Something like

```
class CharRange:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.start <= other <= self.stop
        else:
            return self.start == other.start and self.stop == other.stop

class CharRanges:
    lowercase = CharRange("a", "z")

match "b":
    case "a":
        print("a")
    case CharRanges.lowercase:
        print("alphabet")
```

You can't use `case CharRange("a", "z")` because that's a class pattern, which (without going into how class patterns work) won't help you here, and you can't use

```
x = CharRange("a", "z")
match "b":
    case x:
        ...
```

because `x` is a capture pattern, matching *anything* and binding it to the name `x`.

Comment: Thank you, this is really what I was looking for!
One remaining question: If I make `CharRanges.lowercase` a global variable and add a case to the match statement, why does Python throws `SyntaxError: name capture 'lowercase' makes remaining patterns unreachable`?

Comment: That's a capture pattern like I describe at the end of the answer. A single identifier matches *anything*, so no pattern after it will be considered. (Only *one* pattern in a `match` statement can match.)

Comment: I'm a little surprised it was made a syntax error; it's kind of like making `if False:` a syntax error.

Comment: [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000313/1126841) is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the target value in a list of values, in the case of individual lowercase characters from b-z, you want to use the `in` operator to find your target value.

```
def main():
    target = 'b'
    values = [chr(ascii) for ascii in list(range(ord('b'), ord('z')+1))]
    match target:
        case "a":
            print("a")
        case values if target in values:
            print("alphabet minus a")
        case _:
            print("other")

    return
```

Comment: I forgot about guards.

Comment: For performance considerations, `values` should be a `set`. For this example, you can achieve this by changing line 3 from `values = [...]` to `values = {...}` or (for older Python versions) `values = set(...)`, thus turning the list comprehension into a set comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

We could use regex together with guards to achieve this:

```py
import re

match "b":
    case "a":
        print("a")
    case ch if re.match(r"[a-y]", ch):
        print("found")
    case _:
        print("others")
```

With regex you could easily specify the range (`[a-y]` in this case).